# How to compute HMAC SHA 256 for AWS authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hmac

I'm trying to implement AWS authentication and I'm stuck in the computation of HMAC SHA256.

In their Example Here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html

They are computing

```
HMAC(HMAC(HMAC(HMAC("AWS4" + kSecret,"20150830"),"us-east-1"),"iam"),"aws4_request")
```

With **kSecret** is **wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY**

The result of the function according to them is : **c4afb1cc5771d871763a393e44b703571b55cc28424d1a5e86da6ed3c154a4b9**

I used my own computations as well as HMAC SHA256 generators on internet (they match) and I'm getting :

**8c028f7953b7f2b9fa6d2e816f7b15675dc2329c139e293b383759c5ba8af679**

Does any one know how AWS compute their HMAC SHA256 please ?

Thanks
Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Please note that according to the docs you linked:

> HMAC(key, data) represents an HMAC-SHA256 function that returns output in binary format. The result of each hash function becomes input for the next one.

Ie HMAC() returns a `byte[]` and not a hex string. And it also expects its input as `byte[]`. If your hmac function converts the hash to a hex string before returning the result, you have to make sure, to correctly convert it back to a `byte[]` when using it as key for the next step. Or -- preferrably -- don't convert your intermediate results to string but just pass on the `byte[]` to the next step and only convert the final result to string.

For instance consider the following:

Some hashing function `hash(key, value)` returns `[255, 255]` as result (ie a `byte[]` with two bytes). When you convert that `byte[]` to a hex string you will get the string `"ffff"`. But if you pass this string as a key into the next step, most of the online tools won't treat this string as a hex representation, but just treat each character of the string as a single byte. Ie your string `"ffff"` will become the bytearray `[102, 102, 102, 102]`, which is obviously wrong and leads to a different hashing result.

For JS:

```js
var secret = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";
var date = "20150830";
var region = "us-east-1";
var service = "iam";

var kdate = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(date, "AWS4"+secret);
var kregion = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(region, kdate);
var kservice = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(service, kregion);
var ksigning = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kservice);

var hashInHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(ksigning);
console.log(hashInHex);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
```

Also the `CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(data, key)` treats its input like described above. Ie if `key` is a `string`, each character in the key is treated as a single byte when converting to a bytearray. When `key` is already a `byte[]` its taken as it is. And `HmacSHA256` returns the hash as `byte[]` and not as string.

For C#

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var secret = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";
        var date = "20150830";
        var region = "us-east-1";
        var service = "iam";
        
        var kdate = h(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("AWS4"+ secret), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(date));
        var kregion = h(kdate, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(region));
        var kservice = h(kregion, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(service));
        var ksigning = h(kservice, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("aws4_request"));

        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(ksigning).Replace("-","").ToLower());
        
    }
    
    public static byte[] h(byte[] key, byte[] buffer) {
        var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(key);
        return hmacsha256.ComputeHash(buffer);
    }
    
}
```

Both variants deliver the expected output.